# how to combine multiple files into one

Tags: php, file

I am trying to combine all files into one txt file.However , i can't write texts into  txt file . Here 's my code

```
public function combineFiles($filename,$source)
{
$files = glob("$source/*.??");
$out = fopen("$filename", "w");
foreach ($files as $file) {
        file_put_contents("$source/$filename.txt",$file);       
    }

return $filename.'.txt';

}
```

Comment: what is value of `$filename` ?

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972355/merge-all-files-in-directory-to-one-text-file

Comment: it's name of txt file.

Comment: @hardik solanki , i don't want to use array , all i want is copying text of files and paste into my txt files .

Comment: what will be `$filename` here `fopen("$filename", "w");` if file name is `abc.txt` ? Will it be `abc` or `abc.txt` ? if its `abc` then replace code by `$out = fopen("$filename.txt", "w");` and try

Comment: i tried but it is not worked , i does not write content into file

Comment: Does the file exist? Do you have permissions to write to it?

Comment: $out = fopen("$filename", "w");    with this function i  created the file