# How can I add a new lib path without call each one on the header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

How can I add/call a entire path with all their files inside, without call each one on the header like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

How Wordpress call all the files on the header dynamically?

Comment: Sounds like you need to combine several (css,js) files into one. You can start with this in your terminal on MAC, where "source" is the directory with all your js files: 
`bash cat source/*js > bundle.js`

Comment: I have for example three different stylesheets (with different names, of course), within a path named "custom-stylesheets", how can I add all these with one function?

Comment: Try the bash script or try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972355/merge-all-files-in-directory-to-one-text-file